# How to check Spring Actuator content with Powershell

Tags: powershell, spring-boot-actuator

I want to check the baseurl/actuator/info endpoint for my application in a powershell script.

I have tried running the following command

```
(iwr -Uri $url).Content
```

but run into the following issues

1. The data returned appears to be ascii values or something with each value on it's own line
2. The data returned appears to be html instead of json

Using postman the data is returned just fine. But how can I achieve this in Powershell?

Comment: Try adding `-ContentType application/json -Headers @{Accept = 'application/json'}` to `iwr`

Comment: perfect! If you want to add that as an answer, I can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the `info` endpoint decides on the output format based on the request you send it, so try:

```
(iwr -Uri $url -ContentType application/json -Headers @{ Accept = 'application/json' }).Content
```

Now that Spring knows it's talking to a JSON client, it should send JSON back